# Convert a pandas dataframe function into a more efficient function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Given the following two pandas dataframes

Dataframe 1

```
       open     high      low    close
0  340.649  340.829  340.374  340.511
1  340.454  340.843  340.442  340.843
2  340.521  340.751  340.241  340.474
3  340.197  340.698  340.145  340.420
4  340.332  340.609  340.123  340.128
5  340.092  340.462  339.993  340.207
6  340.179  340.437  339.810  339.983
7  340.296  340.498  339.977  340.036
8  340.461  340.641  340.189  340.367
9  340.404  340.820  340.338  340.589
```

Dataframe 2

```
       ohlc
0  0.374309
1  0.712707
2  0.791436
3  0.761050
4  0.779006
5  0.765193
6  0.578729
7  0.469613
8  0.385359
9  0.511050
```

and the following function which takes the two dataframes and does some normalization and comparison

```
def normalizeAndCompare(df1, df2):
    highest = df1["high"].max()
    lowest = df1["low"].min()

    df1["high"] = ((df1["high"] - lowest) / (highest - lowest))
    df1["low"] = ((df1["low"] - lowest) / (highest - lowest))
    df1["open"] = ((df1["open"] - lowest) / (highest - lowest))
    df1["close"] = ((df1["close"] - lowest) / (highest - lowest))
    df1["ohlc"] = (df1["open"] + df1["high"] + df1["low"] +df1["close"] ) / 4


    df1["highstd"] = df1["high"] + df1["ohlc"].rolling(window=10).std()
    df1["lowstd"] = df1["low"] - df1["ohlc"].rolling(window=10).std()

    df1["highpercent"] = df1["high"] + (df1["high"] * 0.05)
    df1["lowpercent"] = df1["low"] - (df1["low"] * 0.05)

    df1["highstd"] = df1['highstd'].fillna(value=df1['highpercent'])
    df1["lowstd"] = df1['lowstd'].fillna(value=df1['lowpercent'])

    result = (np.where(((df2["ohlc"] <= df1['highstd']) & (df2["ohlc"] >= df1['lowstd'])), 1, 0)).sum()

    return result
```

How can this function be changed so that it would run more efficiently and much faster returning the same result?

Given the fact that i am a newbie to python, i would appreciate very much a bit of help. Here is my setup. Maybe there are also ways to increase efficiency here. I am running a loop on the dataframe1:

```
pd_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=('rowNr', 'result'))
batchSize = 10
for rowNr in  range(len(dataframe1)):
    df1_temp = dataframe1[rowNr: rowNr + batchSize]
    df1_temp = df1_temp.reset_index(drop=True)
    result= normalizeAndCompare(df1_temp, dataframe2)
    pd_result.loc[rowNr] = [rowNr , result]
```

My final result should be the pd_result. 
One more note, dataframe1 is huge, has a few million rows.

Comment: i can provide a little bigger dataframe1 if you needs to test the efficiency and execution time

Comment: You want to *normalize and compare* successive sliding/rolling windows?

Comment: yes @wwii that is exactly what i am trying to do. but i do not know how to optimize this

Comment: With a batch size of 10, ```.rolling(window=10).std()``` doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: it is just for testing purposes. i will increase it later

Comment: Hei @JohnE, thanks for the evaluation of the code. I still believe that there has to be a better way to run this, much faster than regular looping. Looping 1000 rows in dataframe1 i get around 8-9 seconds execution time.It is quite a long time considering that my dataset is a few millions rows.  I tried multiprocessing, it gives just a bit faster results but not what i expect. I will change the hardware but that is the last thing, i want to see how much faster can this code run just by changing the structure or the method i use

Comment: i expect under 1 second for 1000 rows

Comment: @RaduS: I have now removed the CUDA tag twice because this question isn't a CUDA programming question. Please refrain from re-adding  it.

Comment: Btw, I think maybe you are confused about looping and vectorization in pandas.  When you do something like `df['high'].sum()` in pandas, that is already vectorized, you don't need to do anything more.  Now it's still true that you can generally do things faster in numpy, but that's just due to pandas extra overhead.  Which way you go will depend on if you want to spend extra time coding things manually in numpy vs quick and readable pandas code (that is still plenty fast in many cases).

Comment: aha, i did not know that distinction, thank you for clarifying that for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly quick conversion from a mostly-pandas function to a mostly-numpy function (`rolling` is still in pandas, but the rest is numpy).  For 10,000 rows, this is about 10x faster.

```
def norm_comp(df1, df2):

    open  = df1['open'].values
    high  = df1['high'].values
    low   = df1['low'].values
    close = df1['close'].values

    highest = high.max()
    lowest  = low.min()

    high  = ((high  - lowest) / (highest - lowest))
    low   = ((low   - lowest) / (highest - lowest))
    open  = ((open  - lowest) / (highest - lowest))
    close = ((close - lowest) / (highest - lowest))

    ohlc = (open + high + low + close) / 4

    roll_std = pd.Series(ohlc).rolling(10).std().values

    highstd = np.where( np.isnan(roll_std), high * 1.05, high + roll_std )
    lowstd  = np.where( np.isnan(roll_std), low  *  .95, low  - roll_std )

    return np.where(((df2.ohlc.values <= highstd) & 
                     (df2.ohlc.values >= lowstd)), 1, 0).sum()
```

I expanded your sample data to 10,024 rows as follows:

```
for i in range(10): 
    df1 = df1.append(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
    df2 = df2.append(df2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And here are the timings:

```
%timeit normalizeAndCompare(df1,df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.93 ms per loop

%timeit norm_comp(df1,df2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 957 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed the time is much faster. i get about twice as fast as the original function

Comment: What do you mean by "second function" there is only one

Comment: we can actually include **df1['open'].values** and **df1['close'].values** directly in the **open** and **close** variables and then the  **open** and **close** directly in the **ohlc** variable and the **ohlc**  variable directly in the **roll_std** variable.  This way there we reduce the extra variables and increase the speed a little more, the only drawback is that it's a bit more difficult to read

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Btw, I replaced the `fillna` with `np.where` which speeds it up a little more.  I think that's almost all of the low hanging fruit from converting from pandas to numpy.

Comment: with np.where it increased a lot :) Thank YOU